# Pandas : IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to apply a function to each row in the DataFrame and assign the result to new col. My real dataframe is of shape `(1791, 263)` with `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1791, step=1)`

When I attempt to run `.apply` on the DataFrame, I run into the error.

Here's sample code to illustrate what I am doing on my real / large DataFrame.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np

 df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'id': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                    'vals': [[1,3,4,6,3],[3,5,6,2,6],[9,5,6,2,5],[3,5,6,7,3],[3,6,4,7]]
                   })


df['val_rand'] = df.apply(lambda row : np.quantile(random.sample(row['vals'],int(len(row['vals'])/2)),[0.25,0.75]), axis = 1)
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/d0/gnksqzwn2fn46fjgrkp6045c0000gn/T/ipykernel_5131/2407049844.py in <module>
     
----> 1 df['val_rand'] = df.apply(lambda row : np.quantile(random.sample(row['vals'],int(len(row['vals'])/2)),[0.25,0.75]), axis = 1)


/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
   8837             kwargs=kwargs,
   8838         )
-> 8839         return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")
   8840 
   8841     def applymap(

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply(self)
    725             return self.apply_raw()
    726 
--> 727         return self.apply_standard()
    728 
    729     def agg(self):

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    849 
    850     def apply_standard(self):
--> 851         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    852 
    853         # wrap results

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    865             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    866                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 867                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    868                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    869                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

/var/folders/d0/gnksqzwn2fn46fjgrkp6045c0000gn/T/ipykernel_5131/2407049844.py in <lambda>(row)
       
----> 1 df['val_rand'] = df.apply(lambda row : np.quantile(random.sample(row['vals'],int(len(row['vals'])/2)),[0.25,0.75]), axis = 1)


<__array_function__ internals> in quantile(*args, **kwargs)

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in quantile(a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, interpolation, keepdims)
   3928     if not _quantile_is_valid(q):
   3929         raise ValueError("Quantiles must be in the range [0, 1]")
-> 3930     return _quantile_unchecked(
   3931         a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, interpolation, keepdims)
   3932 

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _quantile_unchecked(a, q, axis, out, overwrite_input, interpolation, keepdims)
   3935                         interpolation='linear', keepdims=False):
   3936     """Assumes that q is in [0, 1], and is an ndarray"""
-> 3937     r, k = _ureduce(a, func=_quantile_ureduce_func, q=q, axis=axis, out=out,
   3938                     overwrite_input=overwrite_input,
   3939                     interpolation=interpolation)

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _ureduce(a, func, **kwargs)
   3513         keepdim = (1,) * a.ndim
   3514 
-> 3515     r = func(a, **kwargs)
   3516     return r, keepdim
   3517 

/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in _quantile_ureduce_func(***failed resolving arguments***)
   4048                 indices_below.ravel(), indices_above.ravel(), [-1]
   4049             )), axis=0)
-> 4050             n = np.isnan(ap[-1])
   4051         else:
   4052             # cannot contain nan

IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: This is where testing edge cases is beneficial. Your current example does not produce this `IndexError`, but if I add an extra row with an empty list in the `vals` column or a list with just one value, this exact error comes up.

Comment: If you just do `np.quantile(random.sample([2],int(1/2)),[0.25,0.75])`, i.e., call `np.quantile()` on an empty list, you will get this error.

Comment: @AlexK Yeah, it's likely some edge case(s), I am looking for a way to handle the exceptions. I checked and there are no `NaN`. If there is only 1 value in the list, could we just assign that to the new col.

Comment: Well, that depends on what your goal is for this new column.

Comment: @AlexK the goal is calculate `quantile` from a random sample of values, but if the list has just one value, then assign the single value to the new col.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement this in code?  Try `df['val_rand'] = df.apply(lambda row : np.quantile(random.sample(row['vals'],int(len(row['vals'])/2)),[0.25,0.75]) if len(row['vals']) > 1 else row['vals'], axis = 1)`